# GCD @try @catch @finally

Tags: ios, try-catch, grand-central-dispatch

If I put a try catch and finally inside an async GCD call the finally generally seems to not get executed and I am not sure about the catch either, seems to execute some of the time.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    @try {
        [self methodThatAlwaysThrowsAnException];
    }@catch (NSException *exc) {
        NSLog(@"Caught the Exception %@",exc);
    }@finally{
       NSLog(@"Should always execute");
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Consequently I put the finally call outside of `dispatch_async` but I would prefer to know that my try was fully executed.

Comment: for stuff like this in Cocoa, having methods with NSError parameters that can be checked with a returned result is more common.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid `@try/@catch` for control-flow operations.

Also, your code sample works fine for me. The `@finally` block is always executed, as is the `@catch` block if there was an exception thrown.